# Manually coloring heat map with manual breaks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling making a geom tile plot of a number of chemicals appearing in different devices at varying quantities. X axis will be devices, y axis chemicals and colors fill will be quantity of chemicals in each device.

Now the quantity has a big range from 0.01 to 150000 and is very unsymmetrical like distributed (outliers in both high and low end). So the color fill doesn’t show the quantity properly.

I want the color break in a way so the plot to show all major areas of quantity in different colors.

Below is just sample code of what I am trying so far:

```
ggplot(DataFrame)+
  geom_tile(aes(Device, Chemical, fill=Quantity))+
  scale_fill_steps(low="blue", high="red",  breaks=c( 0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 1000, 150000))
```

But it’s not making what I want. Basically the whole plot is blue except 1/2 red.
How can I make plot showing different color for different quantities that I manually set as breaks for color?

Update 2-16-23:
So I am using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)  
# Define the colors to use 
my_colors <- c("#006837", "#1a9850", "#66bd63", "#a6d96a", "#d9ef8b", "#fee08b", "#fdae61", "#f46d43", "#d73027", "#a50026")  
# Define the breaks to use 
my_breaks <- c(0.001, 0.05, 0.5, 2, 3, 6, 15, 50, 250, 2000, 1500000)
ggplot(DataFrame, aes(Device, Chemical, fill=Quantity)) + geom_tile() + theme_classic() + scale_fill_gradientn(colors = my_colors, breaks = my_breaks))
```

But the plot is like this:

[image]

It is still not showing color for each range of values properly! Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you provide `dput(DataFrame)` or a portion of it?

Comment: Here is portion of dput(DataFrame): structure(list(Device = c("Device_1.", 
"Device_2.", "Device_3.", "Device_4.", .......), Chemical = c("Glutaraldehyde", "Azacyclotridecan-2-one", 
"Isobornyl acrylate", .......), Quantity = c("26", "1.86", 
"330", "257", "12000", ....)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: You might be interested in `scale_fill_gradientn()` where you can provide a colour for every 'break' provided to the `values` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think your breaks are very much shouting "I need a logarithmic scale". You can just log transform your values.

(Had to modify your output a bit, therefore very reduced example)

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Device = c("Device_1.", "Device_2.", "Device_3."), Chemical = c("Glutaraldehyde", "Azacyclotridecan-2-one", "Isobornyl acrylate"), Quantity = c("26", "1.86", "12000"))
df$Quantity <- as.numeric(df$Quantity)

ggplot(df, aes(Device, Chemical, fill=log(Quantity))) + 
  geom_tile()
```

[image]